# Want to get the data in the html table displayed correctly

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I have a question on how to display the correct table layout in my php code:

I want to display answers and their text inputs in a table.. Now at the moment it is displayed as below:

```
QuestionNo   Question             Answer        Marks Per Answer     
1            What is 2+2          B             (text input)         
2            Name the 3 hobbits?  BCE           (text input)
```

I want to change the display of the table so that it looks like this below:

```
 QuestionNo  Question             Answer        Marks Per Answer 
 1           What is 2+2?          B             (text input)
 2           Name the 3 Hobbits?   B             (text input)                   
                                   C             (text input)
                                   E             (text input)
```

1. As you can see from the new display. I want the each answer per question to be displayed in thier own row, not all answers per question in in one row which is what it is doing at moment.
2. I want the text inputs to also be display in its own row, like the answers:

My question is that how can point 1 and 2 be achieved so that it can match the new layout?

Below is the code for the current display:

```
  <?php  
    $assessment = $_SESSION['id'] . $sessionConcat;
    include('connect.php');

    $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, 
    q.QuestionMarks 
    FROM Session s 
    INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
    WHERE s.SessionName = ?
    GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
    ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
    ";

    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 

    // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
    $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
    $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
    }   
    ?>      
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <?php 
echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
      <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
      <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
      </tr>\n";
      $previous_question_id = null;
      foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
        if ($previous_question_id == $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
      $searchQuestionId[$key] = '';
      $question = '';
  }else{
      $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
  }
        echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="answertd">';
        echo $searchAnswer[$key];
        echo '</td>' ;
        echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" "/></td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

    ?>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Below is what the Session, Question and Answer Table looks like:

Session Table:

```
SessionId (auto)  SessionName
1                 AAA
2                 AAB
```

Question Table:

```
SessionId  QuestionId (auto)  QuestionContent
1          1                  What is 2+2?
1          2                  Name the 3 hobbits?
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId (auto) SessionId  QuestionId   Answer
1               1          1           B   
2               1          2           B
3               1          2           C
4               1          2           E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer` to `Answer` and try making this change in the `foreach` loop.

```
$previous_question_id = null;
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
  if ($previous_question_id == $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
    $searchQuestionId[$key] = '';
    $question = '';
  } else {
    $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
  }
```

Comment: I have tried your answer you have kindly given me but I afraid it ha not worked.  In the Answer column in the HTML table, it displays the Answer for question 1 as `BB`, when it should only be `B`, and for question 2 it displays the answer also as `BB` when it should be `BCE`. It is displaying one answer from either question and display it in both questions if that makes sense

Comment: I updated table in question so that it has ncluded your foreach loop

Comment: Replace `foreach($searchAnswer as $key=>$answer){ echo "$answer<br />"; }` by `echo $searchAnswer[$key];`

Comment: Ok nearly there, now what it is doing is only displaying one answer for each question, obviously question one is fine as it is only a single answer as it is displaying answer `B`, for question 2 it has multiple answers but it is only displaying the first of the multiple answers which is also `B`. Code updated

Comment: Remove `an.QuestionId` from the `GROUP BY` clause in the query.

Comment: If I do this then it removes one of the questions

Comment: It removes the second question nd only displays the first question

Comment: Sorry. I am stumped and cannot be of any more help.